# How to change the value after sorting it with np.argsort? (in python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting

I have

```
a = 'first': 3
    'second': 300
b = 'first': 7
    'second':400
```

So each column is defined with 2 different values.
I would only like to rank the 'first' values of each column.

I have a following dataframe:

```
   a b c d e f
0  3 7 8 9 5 1
1  2 0 1 7 5 6 
2  4 6 2 1 9 8
3  5 7 3 1 8 9
```

which i could rank with np.argsort like this:

```
   a b c d e f
0  1 3 4 5 2 0
1  2 0 1 5 3 4 
2  2 3 1 0 5 4
3  2 3 1 0 4 5
```

The values are sorted in ranking (0 = smallest; 5 = biggest)

Now I would like to give a new value for each column but the ranking should stay.

The new value is 'second'.

```
df1 = timeseries[['a','b','c','d']]
df2 = total[['total']]

order = np.argsort(df1, axis=1)

mergelist = pd.concat([order,df2], axis=1)
```

(if there is better way to compare only the 'first' value of an object but still keeping the second, it would be great)

So after this I would like to change the value of each value but still keeping the ranking.

Because in the end I have the list of "total" which I would like to "fill up".

```
    a   b  c  d   e   f   total
0  300 400 50 10 700 100   1000
1  300 400 50 10 700 100   500
2  300 400 50 10 700 100   200
3  300 400 50 10 700 100   1200
```

So each column has its new own value but the ranking should stay.

Now in order to fill up the total, the lowest ranked for each row would start filling up the total. and it should look like this.

```
    a   b  c  d   e   f   total
0  300  0  0  0  600 100   1000
1  50  400 50 0   0   0    500
2   0   0  0  0  200  0    200
3  300 400 50 10 440  0    1200
```

i desperately need helpp

Comment: Where do the 300 and 400 come from?

Comment: how do you get the values of the last column? I cannot see any relation to the original/sorted dataframe of the columns. `300` is `1 * 300`, but where are the `50`, `0` and 2. `300` coming from? (column `a`)?

Comment: 300 and 400 is an another value of a